# Acer Laptop does not power up after repairing DC power jack

Tags: laptop, soldering, acer-travelmate, power-jack

I have an Acer travelmate laptop which (by mistake) I dropped on the floor with the power jack side down, with the charger connected and it broke the DC jack from the inside of the laptop.

Then I unscrewed the laptop and soldered the DC jack back and then plugged it in and switched on the laptop without the batteries. It did switch on, that was before screwing everything back.

Then after assembling the whole thing back it does not power up. So I disassembled it again and just took the part which contained the DC jack (My laptop is like in two parts one contains the power jack which then sits on some pins on the main PCB) to a technician and he said that if you had connected this to a motherboard then it would have burnt cause the soldering was not right.

And then I checked with my laptop again by connecting everything the light (the charging light) comes on when I connect the power but it does not switch on.

Right now nothing is connected to the laptop; no HD, CD ROM, RAM , Battery. Nothing! Even then it does not power up.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Would you please try to put everything back in other than the battery and try again. The only other thing I can think of is that you did more damage than you can see when you dropped it!

Comment: Thanx for the quick reply. I have done that. but what do u say about what the technician said that it was not soldered properly. "he said that if you had connected this to a motherboard then it would have burnt cause the soldering was not right." Can a wrongly soldered Jack cause something to burn or what?

Comment: To be honest soldering something 'wrongly' is so vague it doesn't meant one thing or another. Yes, you could solder it so a connection bridges and then burns it out but it doesn't mean it has! IMO, you need to take it to a computer shop so they can test all components.

Comment: @daverook Well wish i could show you the picture of the "Wrongly" soldered Jack but its been fixed by other person. is there also a possibility that i might have short circuited the jack connection and the motherboard is dead now? Or is it that some component of the motherboard is burnt that can be replaced or something. The thing is the laptop is kinda old so i dont wanna spend a lot on it (actually i prefer not to spend anything on it.)